# Can I choose only portion of a row in UITableView to be clickable(selectable) in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, accordion

So I have a table in the accordion style. When a row is clicked, five radio buttons are displayed. Then, users should be able to click on those buttons. It successfully displays the buttons, but when the buttons are clicked, instead of highlighting the selected button, it shrinks the row itself. I think this is probably because I implemented each set of the label part and the option part as a single row, just in different UIViews. I believe clicking on the view that contains buttons is overridden by clicking on the row(label + options). Its really hard to explain, but I think a solution could be restricting selectrow action of the table to only certain portion of the row.

Is there a way I could achieve this? If I cannnot, is there other ways to implement the accordion table to be used as I described?

I am having a really hard time trying to explain this. If you have any questions, please let me know.

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzHmz.png)

Comment: You question is quite vague, could you post a snippet of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you van give a try to below steps:

- Disable the row selection so that you can avoid row selection. Use`cell.selectionStyle = .none`
- Secondly for your button in row set the IBAction in controller class and in Storyboard connect those actions to specific buttons.